# spring boot application restarts with message "Tomcat started"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, restart

I have a spring-boot application (spring-boot 1.5.9.RELEASE) which restarts (or it  looks like restarts from logs) randomly at any point of time. see logs below.

1. I dont have devtools enabled
2. I do not have jmxremote enabled
3. I do not call make /refresh call
4. I do use spring cloud config

but still application restarts in less than an hour(sometimes within 3 minutes)

```
2018-05-28 09:50:43.108  INFO [pool-3-thread-3] myclass1 : myMessage1
2018-05-28 09:50:43.112  INFO [pool-2-thread-2] myclass2 : myMessage2
2018-05-28 09:50:43.118  INFO [pool-1-thread-3] myclass3 : myMessage3
2018-05-28 09:50:43.214  INFO [main] TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-05-28 09:50:43.221  INFO [main] Application                      : Started Application ... ... ...
```

Comment: I typically see this when there is something causing the application to crash.

Comment: can we get the complete logs?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure a web server is not started in your spring boot application, you can set the following configuration key

spring.main.web-environment=false
Or you can use the SpringApplicationBuilder

new SpringApplicationBuilder(YourApp.class)
        .web(false).run(args);